# Need to read 4 specific columns/fields of data that appear in many different input files with varied column order

Tags: python, dictionary, built-in, file-structure

I'm writing a function to read and transform a series of input txt files.

Each input file can have a different file structure with a different number of columns with columns in varied order. There are four particular columns that appear in all of the input txt files and they each have the same header label. These four columns are the only columns that are relevant data for my purposes.

So for example, let's say I have 2 files where I need to extract only four common columns in each file. One file has 50 columns and a second one has 35 columns, but both files have the 4 columns I need with the same titles: 'SPORT', 'AGE', 'GENDER', and 'HEIGHT'.

Also, the files might be like 200 MB or more and focus on using Python built-ins, so I'm trying to write code that is not memory expensive and I'm trying to use dictionaries and avoid using modules like Pandas or Numpy.

I'm not even sure where to start with this.

Comment: If the files have a header line, parse the header line to figure out which columns you need to extract and in which order.

Comment: @tripleee The files have a header line. How do I parse it?

Comment: Really? Open the file, read a line, probably split on a delimiter. Including a sample of a few lines of a file in the question might be a good idea if you need help with even the most basic Python facilities (in which case perhaps this question is too broad).

Comment: @tripleee Your response is not fair. I know how to parse a file in Python. My specific question here was about how to go about writing code that will parse two separate files with different structures but some of the same common columns. The response at the top of a similar question answered previously shows that this is a question that merits a novel approach that goes beyond some basic, vague suggestion to "parse the header line to figure out which columns you need to extract and in which order."

Comment: Perhaps I was being a bit harsh; but you have certainly been here long enough that you should be familiar with some basic princples of how to ask, perhaps best summarized in the [mcve] guidance. Surely you know how this site reacts to a question with no code, no data, and a fairly frequently asked question (though perhaps not *that* often asked for Python specifically).